# Get num of ROWS in other table

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I have two tables EXERCISE and EXERCISEUSER. I need to list all exercise entries and put an additional field in the query, which will return if that exercise exists in the table EXERCISEUSER. In other words, I need know if the user did that exercise. If so, it will have a row in EXERCISEUSER.

My current query is:

```
SELECT
    "E".*,
    "T"."NAME" AS "LEVEL"
FROM
    "EXERCISE" AS "E"
INNER JOIN
    "EXERCISETYPE" AS "T"
ON
    E.STO_FK_EXERCISETYPEEXERCISE = T.PK_EXERCISETYPE
INNER JOIN
    "LEVEL" AS "L"
ON
    L.PK_LEVEL = E.STO_FK_LEVELEXERCISE
WHERE
    (
        E.STATUS = 1)
AND (
        L.STATUS = 1)
AND (
        L.PK_LEVEL = 5)
ORDER BY
    "T"."ORDER" ASC
```

I will provide PK_USER too.

Thanks!

---

Well, i use a subquery, and reach the result i want.

```
SELECT
    "E".*,
    "T"."NAME" AS "LEVEL",
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STOUSER.EXERCISEUSER AS EU WHERE EU.STO_FK_EXERCISEEXERCISEUSER = E.PK_EXERCISE AND EU.STO_FK_USEREXERCISEUSER = 5978 ) AS MAKE_EXER_NUM
FROM
    "STOUSER"."EXERCISE" AS "E"
INNER JOIN
    "STOUSER"."EXERCISETYPE" AS "T"
ON
    E.STO_FK_EXERCISETYPEEXERCISE = T.PK_EXERCISETYPE
INNER JOIN
    "STOUSER"."LEVEL" AS "L"
ON
    L.PK_LEVEL = E.STO_FK_LEVELEXERCISE
WHERE
    (
        E.STATUS = 1)
AND (
        L.STATUS = 1)
AND (
        L.PK_LEVEL = 5)
ORDER BY
    "T"."ORDER" ASC
```

Thanks!

Comment: If your last edit is the solution to your problem, please post it as an answer and mark it as the answer instead of editing it in to your original question.

Comment: Correlated subqueries are often the most inefficient way to query, use derived tables instead. And never use select *!

Comment: Only the query optimizer can be the judge of that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be done with a LEFT OUTER JOIN.